# Cannot insert duplicate record in a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I am trying to execute stored proc through SSIS and it gives me following error:

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing
>   the query "Exec  sp1 ?" failed with
>   the following error: "Procedure: sp1
>   Line: 66 Message: Cannot insert
>   duplicate key row in object
>   'table.sq1' with unique index
>   'UIX_sp1_Key'.". Possible failure
>   reasons: Problems with the query,
>   "ResultSet" property not set
>   correctly, parameters not set
>   correctly, or connection not
>   established correctly.

Actually the stored Proc `sp1` is truncating & reloading a data into a table.
I am not able to figure out where exactly its trying to insert duplicate record.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I am not able to figure out where exactly its trying to insert duplicate record." - we have less info than you do, so how are we supposed to determine which record?

Comment: Well see what fields are on the unique index `'UIX_sp1_Key'`, then compare that to what records are being inserted. Nothing really more we can advise without some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data must have duplicate values across the key column(s).  You could remove the primary key temporarily (or create another table with the same structure but without the definition of the primary key, but that would mean changing the stored procedure), then load the data into the table.  Then use this SQL statement:

```
select keycol1 {,keycol2 {,keycol3} ...}, count(*)
from tablename
group by keycol1 {,keycol2 {,keycol3} ...}
having count(*) > 1
```

That will show you the data values that are duplicates across the key column(s).

Answer (score 2):

If you are truncating the table before load, then you **must have** duplicate data in the source.

Examine this to see what there is. use Excel or Access or some such if needed to assist. Or drop the unique constraint then query the staging table with an aggregate query.